# IntelliJ ResolutionException on Java modules - contains package/exports package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-module

I wrote a Java module `a.b.c` and another module `d.e.f` that requires `a.b.c`. I'm using IntelliJ.

First module's `module-info.java`:

```java
module a.b.c {
  exports a.b.c;
  requires org.jfree.jfreechart;
  requires commons.cli;
  requires java.desktop;
  requires java.net.http;
}
```

Second module's `module-info.java`:

```java
module d.e.f {
    requires a.b.c;
    requires org.json;
}
```

Both modules compile. When I run `d.e.f`, I get the following error.

```text
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module a.b.c contains package org.jfree.chart.ui, module org.jfree.jfreechart exports package org.jfree.chart.ui to a.b.c
```

These modules aren't split as there is no redundant package between them.

- What does this message mean?
- How do I resolve it?

Comment: Does `a.b.c` explicitly defines a package `org.jfree.chart.ui` apart from the `exports` in  `org.jfree.chart.ui`?

Comment: No. To verify, I did a search for `org.jfree.chart.ui` throughout the entire module `a.b.c`, nothing found. The package `org.jfree.chart.ui` ([link](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ui/package-summary.html)) is actually part of the the Jfree library. Does this error occur because JFree is actually an anonymous module in my project's context?

Comment: How do you package the module `a.b.c` to make use of it in `d.e.f`? are you shading all the classes? Since that could be the only possibility of the message reading *Module `a.b.c` contains package `org.jfree.chart.ui`*, or else a minimal example or project link shall be great to try and reproduce the problem. I assume you wanted to quote `automatic` module instead of `anonymous`.

Comment: Yes, my previous comment should mention `automatic` and not anonymous. The root cause of this message is indeed a configuration setting in IntelliJ. When I build the artifacts and run the jar from the command line, the program runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the `ResolutionException` error because my IntelliJ project was not set up correctly. The best guidance I found was at [Java 9 Modules with IntelliJ IDE Quick Start](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/getting-started-in-intellij.html). Both modules now run without any compile- or run-time errors.